# Change the text of the [ask] magic link to "How to Ask a Good Question"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, magic-links

I (and I'm sure most of you) often type comments like this:

> Blah blah blah... please read [ask] blah blah

..which gets expanded to:

> Blah blah blah... please read [How to Ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) blah blah

This has bugged me for a while and I think the text should be changed to "How to Ask a Good Question" instead of just "How to Ask" for two reasons:

1. The current text often comes off as rude; especially, when the question is not that terrible but just off-topic for one reason or another and could be improved. Telling someone to *"go read 'how to ask'"* could be interpreted as something like  *"go learn how to ask because you obviously can't"* and often triggers a defensive behavior. "How to Ask a Good Question", on the other hand, focuses on the positive because "good" suggests "well-received". At least that's my opinion.
2. The title of the Help Center article is already *"How do I ask **a good question**?"*.

Note that this won't affect the comment's maximum character limit because the limit is applied to the markdown, not the rendered text. Thanks, [@Sonic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-masked-werehog) for reminding me.

Comment: Considering the Help Center only helps in posting the bare minimum of an acceptable question, not a *good* question, this would just trade one inconsistency for another.